# Does anyone knows how to program a 5MP Arducam on a PICO using microPython?

Tags: camera, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to use an ARDUCAM with a Raspberry PICO, but want to use microPython and not C++
Tried to search for tutorials but did not found any.
The Arducam is a SPI camera, not an usb model.
The github https://github.com/ArduCAM/PICO_SPI_CAM/tree/master/Python contains some examples, but seems to be for circuitpython.
How can I get information how to convert or what are the mains differences between the 2 versions of python ?